# Как правильно оправить ajax запрос и получить ответ в переменную в этом же файле

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Есть файл, соединение с сервером успешно, как зарегистрировать Get так что-бы отправить его в этом же документе и взять с него данные. например `$_GET['q']`, так что бы с ними можно было работать в этом же документе?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   function getCHeckedBut() {
     var chekd = $("#q_1").children("input[value='1']");
     chekd.attr('checked', "checked");
   }

   function getCHeckedBut2() {
     var chekd = $("#q_2").children("input[value='1']");
     chekd.attr('checked', "checked");
   }

   function getCHeckedBut3() {
     var chekd = $("#q_3").children("input[value='1']");
     chekd.attr('checked', "checked");
   }

   function getCHeckedBut4() {
     var chekd = $("#q_4").children("input[value='1']");
     chekd.attr('checked', "checked");
   }

   function getCHeckedBut5() {
     var chekd = $("#q_5").children("input[value='1']");
     chekd.attr('checked', "checked");
   }

   function unChekAll() {
     $("#q_1").children("input[value='1']").attr('checked', "");
     $("#q_2").children("input[value='2']").attr('checked', "");
     $("#q_3").children("input[value='3']").attr('checked', "");
     $("#q_4").children("input[value='4']").attr('checked', "");
     $("#q_5").children("input[value='5']").attr('checked', "");
   }
   $("#q_1").on('click', unChekAll, getCHeckedBut);
   $("#q_2").on('click', unChekAll, getCHeckedBut2);
   $("#q_3").on('click', unChekAll, getCHeckedBut3);
   $("#q_4").on('click', unChekAll, getCHeckedBut4);
   $("#q_5").on('click', unChekAll, getCHeckedBut5);
 })


 function vote_quest(form) {

   //if (form.q.value == null || form.q.value)
   alert(form.q.value);
   var link = "/index.php?action=vote_q&q_tbl_num=" + form.q.value + "&q=" + form.q.value;
   var cont = document.getElementById('vote_cont');
   var loading = document.getElementById('vote_loading');

   cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;
   alert("working");
   var http = createRequestObject();
   if (http) {
     http.open('get', link);
     http.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (http.readyState == 4) {
         cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;
         alert('Сервер');
       }
     }
     http.send(null);
     update_quest_tabl_num();
   } else {
     document.location = link;
   }
 }

 function update_quest_tabl_num() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "/index.php?action=next_vote",
     cache: false,
     success: function() {
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'Хеллоу';
     }
   });
 }

 function createRequestObject() {
   try {
     return new XMLHttpRequest()
   } catch (e) {
     try {
       return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
     } catch (e) {
       try {
         return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
       } catch (e) {
         return null;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

```html
<?php
var_dump($_GET['q_1']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['q_2']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['q_3']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['q_4']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['q_5']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['vote_q']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['q_tbl_num']); echo '<br />';
var_dump($_GET['q']); echo '<br />';

if ($_GET['action'] == 'vote_q' && $_GET['q_tbl_num'] && $_GET['q']) {
    echo '<script>alert("Гет есть");</script>';
}


if ($_GET['action'] == 'vote_q') { //по нажатию vote вызываем запись
    if (!empty($_GET['q_tbl_num']) || isset($_GET['q_tbl_num'])) {
        if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {
            echo '<script>alert("Гет етсь и здесь");</script>';
        } 
    }
}

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <td class="width_b" id="w_b_height" valign="top"></td>
  <!--questionnarie -->
  <div id="quest_wrap" class="quest_bg" style="min-width: 380px; height: 500px; max-width: 410px; max-height: 600px; border-radius: 2%; border:solid 1px #4c231f; position: absolute;">
    <div class="questionnaire" style="height: 58px; border-radius: 5%; "></div>
    <div id="test" style="height: 75%; position: static;">

      <form method="get" action="">

        <br />
        <center class="questionnaire_text" style="font-size: 1.4em;">{NAMEQ}</center>
        <br />
        <div class="questionnaire_text" id="q_1" style=" margin-left: 10%;  vertical-align: middle;  padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
          <input type="radio" name="q" value="1"><a style="padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 1.5em; margin-left: 10px;">first</a>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="questionnaire_text" id="q_2" style=" margin-left: 10%;  vertical-align: middle;  padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
          <input type="radio" name="q" value="2"><a style="padding-bottom: 1px; font-size: 1.5em; margin-left: 10px;">second</a>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="q_tbl_num" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="quest_but_l" style="bottom: 0px; position: absolute; height: 60px;">
      <input type="button" value="Проголосовать" class="button_quest" style="bottom: 0px; margin: auto; position: static;" onClick="vote_quest(this.form);"></input>
    </div>

    </form>



  </div>
  <div id="vote_cont" style="display: none"></div>
  <div id="vote_loading" style="display: none"></div>

  <!--/ -->
  </td>
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: масло масляное. попытайтесь вразумительно объяснить, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @teran, lчто за масло, сори без стилей? Хочу что бы гет был, и хочу взять с него 'q'

Comment: используйте метод [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/): `$.get("/index.php", { q : 123 }, function(data){ ... })` отправит вам ajax-запрос, и передаст параметр `q`, который на сервере вы получите в `$_GET['q']`. В целом можете в запросе просто указать параметр прямо в URL: `$.get("/index.php?q=123", function(data){ ... })`, то же самое. В `data` получите ответ сервера.

Comment: а масло-масляное потому что первые 20-30 строк вашего кода практически повторяются по 5 раз для каждого `q`. +одновременно мешаете чистый js и jquery. Почему в одном месте вы пишите `$("#q_1")` а в другом `document.getElementById("test").innerHtml = ".."`, если это то же самое, что `$("#test").html("...")`. Используете `$.ajax()` и рядом же создаете вручную `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: и в попытке прикрутить обработчики кликов в `.on()` у вас вторым параметром откуда то взялся непонятный метод, хотя там должен быть строковый селектор.

Comment: @teran, да, здесь немного лишнего кода выложил, люблю больше чистый js, но с jquery все таки быстрее. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @teran вы слишком агрессивны к новичкам. вопрос был по ajax а не по тому, как правильно писать код

Comment: @webDev_ да не было агрессии вроде в моих комментах, я весьма терпимо отношусь к такому коду в вопросах. Я часто обращаю внимание на такие моменты по коду, но не для того чтобы сказать человеку что его код, так сказать не очень, а пытаюсь кратко разъяснить, что именно там не очень, дабы человек понял и старался впредь писать более качественно, указать на ошибки, что бы мотивировать к более глубокому изучению.